# overwriting "|" operator to concatenate numpy arrays

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am wondering how to overload/overwrite the `|` operator to concatenate (two-dimensional) numpy arrays along the second axis, so that

```
u = np.array([[7], [8], [9]])
v = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
w = u | v
```

produces the same result as

```
u = np.array([[7], [8], [9]])
v = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
w = np.concatenate((u, v), axis=1)
```

i.e., results in

```
[[7, 1, 2],
 [8, 3, 4],
 [9, 5, 6]]
```

being assigned to `w`.

NB: The original meaning of `|` is elucidated in the first comment below.

PS: I am willing to edit the numpy source code.

Comment: `u | v <=> u.__or__(v)`;  element wise `or`.  It will make most sense if `u` and `v` are boolean or 0/1.   For lists, and strings, `+` is the overloaded operator for `join`.

Comment: Have you made any effort to figure out how the existing operator implemented, or do you want us to do that for you too?

Comment: @Mad Physicist: Thanks for the constructive feedback. Please forgive me for coming here for help.

Comment: There's a difference between asking for help and asking someone to do your work for you without any effort on your own part.